# What is entity manager in symfony 2 and how it works internally?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity

Can anybody please help me to understand the concept of entity manager, what it is, how it works and why we need it ?

Comment: Do you know what it *is*? If not why don't you look it up on the internet first?

Comment: I searched on internet, but everywhere how to use it is given but the its internal working and concept i could not find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Interface used to interact with the persistence context.
>
> An EntityManager instance is associated with a persistence context. A persistence context is a set of entity instances in which for any persistent entity identity there is a unique entity instance. Within the persistence context, the entity instances and their lifecycle are managed. The EntityManager API is used to create and remove persistent entity instances, to find entities by their primary key, and to query over entities.
>
> The set of entities that can be managed by a given EntityManager instance is defined by a persistence unit. A persistence unit defines the set of all classes that are related or grouped by the application, and which must be colocated in their mapping to a single database.

Taken from [Java EE API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html). Doctrine's `EntityManager` is based on JPA so the description is the same.